# How to get the vertices of detected rectangle in an image

Tags: opencv, rectangles, vertices

I am new to opencv and I need to detect a rectangle in an image, get its vertices and by using those points, I have to crop that image. Rectangle is detected by finding contours. Now I want to get the vertices (corner values). Can anyone please guide or share the code?

My code is:

```
 CvSeq* contours;  //hold the pointer to a contour in the memory block
 CvSeq* result;   //hold sequence of points of a contour
 CvMemStorage *storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0); //storage area for all contours

 //finding all contours in the image
 cvFindContours(imgGrayScale, storage, &contours, sizeof(CvContour), CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, cvPoint(0,0));

 //iterating through each contour
 while(contours)
 {
     //obtain a sequence of points of contour, pointed by the variable 'contour'
     result = cvApproxPoly(contours, sizeof(CvContour), storage, CV_POLY_APPROX_DP, cvContourPerimeter(contours)*0.02, 0);

      //if there are 4 vertices in the contour(It should be a rectangle)
     if(result->total==4 )
     {
         //iterating through each point
         CvPoint *pt[4];
         for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
            {
                pt[i] = (CvPoint*)cvGetSeqElem(result, i);
         }

         //drawing lines around the rectangle
         cvLine(img, *pt[0], *pt[1], cvScalar(0,255,0),4);
         cvLine(img, *pt[1], *pt[2], cvScalar(0,255,0),4);
         cvLine(img, *pt[2], *pt[3], cvScalar(0,255,0),4);
         cvLine(img, *pt[3], *pt[0], cvScalar(0,255,0),4);
     }
      //obtain the next contour
     contours = contours->h_next;
}
```

Comment: Please explain the specific problem you are having with the code you have posted.

Comment: since you're new to opencv, they switched to a c++ api in 2010 already. please try to use that, not the old c-api ! avoid IplImages, cv*functions, use cv::Mat and objects from the cv::namespace.

Comment: I am using version 2.4.2 of Opencv. The problem I am facing is, I want to detect the vertices of rectangle in order to crop the image by using those points of vertices. The top left and bottom right points.

Comment: @savanna - I dont have problem with this code. Just posted it for refernce and want to know how can I get the vertices as I have detected rectangle using contours function.

Comment: AFAIK, the detected contours (at least with the C++ API) hold contiguous points, so a rectangle will **not** hold only 4 points but many more, so your code kinda surprises me. Are you sure this correctly draws the rectangles ?

Comment: yes it is drawing only a filled rectangle.

Comment: Please anyone can guide for the method, how can I get the vertices which I have to use further for crop function.